# Using Kotlin synthetic properties

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, kotlin

I'm trying Vert.x in Kotlin. I have the following piece of code:

```
val deploymentOptions = DeploymentOptions()
deploymentOptions.setConfig(JsonObject().put("http.port", 8081))
```

Everything works fine. However, IntelliJ IDEA reports on the second line that I should use "Kotlin synthetic properties".

Any idea how to do that in this case. Also, I'm using Maven.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hit alt+enter on that line. IDEA should suggest you a solution. Pick one.

Probably:

`deploymentOptions.config = JsonObject().put("http.port", 8081)`

Answer (score 4):

In [Kotlin documentation for Java interop](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#getters-and-setters), it talks about getters and setters and how they relate to properties:

> Methods that follow the Java conventions for getters and setters (no-argument methods with names starting with get and single-argument methods with names starting with set) are represented as properties in Kotlin.

And it provides the example:

```
import java.util.Calendar

fun calendarDemo() {
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    if (calendar.firstDayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY) {  // call getFirstDayOfWeek()
        calendar.firstDayOfWeek = Calendar.MONDAY       // call setFirstDayOfWeek()
    }
}
```

The tip you are receiving in your IDE is telling you that it is better (idiomatic) to use the property syntax instead of calling a getter or setter directly.  Therefore instead of using:

```
deploymentOptions.setConfig(...)
```

You would use:

```
deploymentOptions.config = ...
```